# How to install PyQt4 in angstrom

Tags: pyqt4, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to install pyqt4 in Beagle Bone Black Angstrom distribution. I've tried with

```
opkg update && opkg install pyqt4
```

and says there's no package named pyqt4.

I've seen here something saying this could work

```
opkg update && opkg install qt4-x11-free-dev
```

Also didn't worked

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why do your don't try python setup install. Download source pyqt4 and install it by using 'python setup.py install'.

Comment: I've tried this. As far as I advanced, I have to first install SIP, then instal qt4 and then install pyqt4. I've successfully installed SIP and I'm trying to instan qt4. Those opkg packages of qt are not enough and usually send a error of no qmake file found.